# How do I locate and block a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, block

A website that I'm using has an annoying pop-up that randomly appears on the screen every x minutes. Inside the Chrome developer tool bar using the 'break on subtree modifications' option, I can see that it's calling insertBefore and removeChild functions inside of jquery-2.0.3.min.js. Specifically the following.

```
        before: function() {
            return this.domManip(arguments, function(e) {
                this.parentNode && this.parentNode.insertBefore(e, this)
            })
        },
        after: function() {
            return this.domManip(arguments, function(e) {
                this.parentNode && this.parentNode.insertBefore(e, this.nextSibling)
            })
        },
        remove: function(e, t) {
            var n, r = e ? x.filter(e, this) : this, i = 0;
            for (; null != (n = r[i]); i++)
                t || 1 !== n.nodeType || x.cleanData(mt(n)),
                n.parentNode && (t && x.contains(n.ownerDocument, n) && dt(mt(n, "script")),
                n.parentNode.removeChild(n));
            return this
        },
```

On the website itself it generates a div with a random css id, hangs around for a minute then disappears.

It doesn't look like any particular event is causing this to fire.

Do you have any tips on how I can find out more about what's happening and how I can block it? I believe I should be able to block this using something like greasemonkey.

Any insight would be much appreciated, plus this has been a valuable learning experience so far.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: In the browser's debugger, you can typically see a stack trace view in the right panel. This tells you what called the jQuery functions. Can you find the actual calling code there? If not, try setting a breakpoint as early as possible in the code, then patch window.setTimeout and window.setInterval to have a `debugger;` statement - that way you can find all locations that call those functions. Or in that early breakpoint call `monitor(setTimeout)` in Chrome's devtools' console to monitor all calls.

Comment: @cbr Thank you for your input, this has helped greatly. I was able to find the source of what's generating this pop-up. Next steps are to figure out how to block it now. I can't accept your post as answered as it's a comment, if you can amend I will do that. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! You could just create a filter to delete the popup element with a browser extension such as uBlock Origin (and potentially also remove overflow:hiddens from the body or html element if the popup applies it), or add some custom JS for the domain with a Tampermonkey user script.

Comment: Sorry, just reread your question. If the ID is random, perhaps the content is not? E.g. some title text or body text which you can target with a :has-text() in uBlockO or with a .textContent.includes() in a Greasemonkey script inside a setInterval or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser's debugger, you can typically see a stack trace view in the right panel. This tells you what called the jQuery functions.

If you can't see the trace, e.g. the stack trace mysteriously begins from some async code or requestAnimationFrame, set a breakpoint as early as possible in the code, then patch `window.setTimeout` and `window.setInterval` to have a `debugger;` statement - that way you can find all locations that call those functions.

Or, in that early breakpoint, call monitor(setTimeout) in Chrome's devtools' console to monitor all calls.

Comment: I managed to figure out how to block it in the end. So the function generates a random css class id that's between 4 and 6 characters long. I used the MutationObserver method to monitor for changes, then I had to target anything new that had a CSS ID between 4 and 6 characters otherwise it would block other elements on the page. I put this inside of tampermonkey and it works! No more annoying random pop-up every few minutes. 

Unfortunately I can't mark your answer as useful as I don't have at least 15 reputation but your post lead me to the solution, thanks again!